# Erlang consumer queue

Tags: io, erlang, queue, throughput

I have a problem where I want to pull discrete chunks of data from disk into a *queue*, and *dequeue* them into another process. This data is randomly located on disk, so would not benefit substantially from sequential reads. It's alot of data so I can't load it all at once, nor is it efficient to pull in a block at a time.

I'd like the consumer to be able to operate at its own speed, but to keep a healthy queue of data ready for it so that I'm not constantly waiting on disk reads as I process chunks.

Is there an established way to do this? I.e with the jobs framework or safetyvalve? Implementing this feels like reinventing the wheel as a slow consumer operating on disk data is a common problem.

Any suggestions as to how best to tackle this the *Erlang* way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `{read_ahead, Bytes}` option on [`file:open/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2):

> `{read_ahead, Size}`
>
> This option activates read data buffering. If `read/2` calls are for significantly less than `Size` bytes, read operations towards the operating system are still performed for blocks of `Size` bytes. The extra data is buffered and returned in subsequent `read/2` calls, giving a performance gain since the number of operating system calls is reduced.
>
> The `read_ahead` buffer is also highly utilized by the `read_line/1` function in `raw` mode, why this option is recommended (for performance reasons) when accessing raw files using that function.
>
> If `read/2` calls are for sizes not significantly less than, or even greater than `Size` bytes, no performance gain can be expected.

You've been vague on the sizes you mentioned using, but it seems that toying with that buffer size should be a decent start implementing what you need.

Comment: Read ahead will load more data on each read so that subsequent reads have better throughput, but the reads are not consecutive. I'm reading data that is scattered all over the underlying file. So this may help sometimes, but buffering inbound data into a queue that is sequentially consumed would be better. I was thinking a jobs queue that fills up to a certain threshold and then is drained by the consumer at its own pace would make the most sense, but jobs doesn't seem particularly geared for this use case.

Comment: I would update the original question with that information then.

Comment: I've made that edit. I'll implement read_ahead just to test my assumptions about performance, thanks for the advice.